# VS'13: Cannot Sign in to the Windows Store, "... unable to verify your developer account."

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

For the last few days I've been getting an error when trying to create app packages for the Windows 8 store: "Visual Studio was unable to verify your developer account. Either the store is unavailable or an unexpected network error has occured."

[image: Visual Studio was unable to verify your developer account. Either the store is unavailable or an unexpected network error has occured.]

Have other people experienced this or do people know a what could be causing this? I'm running Windows 10 on VMWare Fusion. This is the first time I ran into this problem.

Comment: experiencing this right now. Not in vmware, just normal windows 10, visual studio 2013

Comment: Very annoying. I talked to some MS people and they asked me to write an email to product support, but it looks like VS '13 community does not get free support. I'll keep this post updated in case I found something out. Let me know if you solve it some way.

Comment: seems like one of those things that just sorts itself out if you wait a bit, but it's frustrating that there's no way to communicate with them and get the issue sorted sooner. I can't really wait.

Comment: I've experienced this already for two weeks now, so I'm not sure if it will go away...

Comment: I've read that it isn't going away, that VS2013 can no longer build for 8.1 apps

Comment: Do you have a resource? If you write it up as an answer I can select your answer.

Comment: @TKoL: I can't find any information about it. Can you share with me where you read that?

Comment: Sorry, I read it last week and did not save the link. Might have been on the microsoft forums

Comment: The same issue described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224037/no-way-to-publish-app.html).

Comment: Now it works for me, I was able to associate the app with the store and also create new build of the app.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me too now.

Comment: Were you able to upload the packages? For me, the "Drag your packages here (.appx, .appxbundle, .appxupload, .xap) or browse your files." area is not accepting any files...

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft this is a problem again. It's been going on for multiple weeks now. Should we be able to build projects from Visual Studio 2013? I'm trying to build a winJs store app.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT hoping we can get someone fro mmicrosoft to look at this again